# Mongodb: split a part of string as a new filed

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new in mongodb.

I have these kind of strings that I get from my mongodb collection:

```
"DeliveryParams" : [],
"Address" : "09360951914",
"Payload" : "{\"Id\":\"4573358d-8cac-44a4-85e0-2343wres4321\",\"CreationDateTime\":\"\\/Date(1477834196111)\\/\",\"DeviceId\":\"\",\"UserId\":\"b9cdd9d3-4ac8-4f95-8s44-1234wre44321\",\"UserFullName\":\"groot\",\"SystemId\":\"monitoring\",\"SystemTitle\":\"monitoring\",\"EventId\":\"monitoring.events.udutyallcalculates\",\"EventTitle\":\"xxxx\",\"EventData\":[{\"Key\":\"LogID\",\"Value\":\"\",\"Children\":null},{\"Key\":\"SessionId\",\"Value\":\"GUID\",\"Children\":null},{\"Key\":\"Version\",\"Value\":\"Host- Version=1111\",\"Children\":null}],\"BusinessCode\":\"2-10-102606-46-1-0-0\",\"ProcessId\":\"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000\",\"WorkItemId\":ttt,\"WKT\":\"\"}"
```

how could I split just this `\"BusinessCode\":\"2-10-102606-46-1-0-0\"` section at **Payload** field?

because I want to add this section (**BusinessCode**) as a **new field** into my collection!!! 
does it have mongodb any method for do this scenario?

Comment: what you are asking for sounds very specific and a "business logic" piece that should be part of your application functionality -- its not something that MongoDB (or any database) can do for you.  When you were creating/writing records, the split should have happened then -- on the way into the database

Comment: Unfortunately, this situation was not predicted in the past and now I need to do this plan.I have to find a solution for this.

Comment: How large is the collection?  You can loop through the records, split them, and update the existing records with new fields OR create a whole new collection

Comment: there are 6 million document into collection.my main problem is spiting. I have to use `BusinessCode`as a split-er? or how can i split just BusinessCode and it's values?

Comment: 6 million documents is nothing -- you can rip through it in seconds. Do a query, get the documents/records one by one -- massage the record any way you like (changing the payload or creating additional fields) and update the record back to the database. See the documentation on how to update a  record